# I need a script to show different banner based on state or city using visitor IP address

Tags: content-management-system, ads, advertisement-server

I need tips on a simple ad management script/software that allows me to set specific locations with city and/or state for the banner to show.

Im using wordpress

thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request/task and not practical problem.

Comment: Thats not what i am trying to do... i need the tips on how to do it... your a loser

Comment: Well, tips: Pick a language (and environment and ancillary technology). Learn it. Use it do stuff. Hope that helps!

Comment: You are still a goof ball

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch visitor city/state via php or js using geoplugin json web service:
http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=129.74.193.44